# Samsung GT-S7562: Network Goes off

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cyanogenmod, custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

I have Samsung GT-S7562. I did update the handset with KyleOPEN custom ROM. Was not satisfied with the custom ROM so again ported back to Original ROM.

I updated the ROM + Kernel using Odin tool. After I update, the network goes off suddenly. I have re-register with the service provider to gain the network back. This happened thrice.

Also, is there Cyanogenmod or any other custom ROM (Apart from KyleOPEN)for this handset.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: If the phone's not listed on the Cyanogenmod website, there's no Cyanogenmod for it.

Comment: For the second part of your question, you might want to take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Answer (score -2):

you've lost the efs file that contains the serial number

Comment: That could be right. It's not very helpful in itself: do you have a suggestion for what Nishith can do about it?